# Как заменить курсор мыши на свой при drag and drop

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css3

css

```
.draggable,
.draggable * {
    cursor: url('img/arrowHand.png'), auto;
}
```

js

```
$('body').on('dragstart', function () {
    $('body').addClass('draggable');
});
$('body').on('dragend', function () {
    $('body').removeClass('draggable');
});
```

Класс присваивается, картинка курсора подгружается, но курсор стандартный при перетаскивании объекта

Answer (score 0):

Для замены курсора нужно использовать файл в формате **.cur**.

Вот рабочий [**онлайн-конвертор**](http://convertio.co/ru/png-cur/) (кликабельно)