# Изменение курсора мыши cursor:(путь к иконе), pointer;

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

Господа, читаю документацию, вроде все понятно и проще пареной перы...

```css
    .cur {
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        border: 1px solid orange;
         font-size: 20px;
    }

    #cur_1 {

        cursor: url(http://webcodius.ru/images/cursor.cur), pointer;
    }
    #cur_2 {

        cursor: url(http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-uIY8CwnjM-c/VHbcXXC9HmI/AAAAAAAAAT8/3uwp5nSIWEU/s1600/Mouse%2BIcon.png), pointer;
    }
    #cur_3 {
      cursor: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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) 16 16, crosshair;
    }
    #cur_4 {
     /*а это путьк той же картинке из cur_2 скаченная ко мне на комп*/

        cursor: url(Icon/Mouse_Icon.png), pointer;

    }
    #cur_5 {
     /*а это путьк той же картинке из cur_2 скаченная ко мне на комп*/

        cursor: url(Icon/Mouse Icon.png), pointer;

    }
```

```html
    <div id="cur_1" class="cur">1</div>
    <div id="cur_2" class="cur">2</div>
    <div id="cur_3" class="cur">3</div>
    <div id="cur_4" class="cur">4</div>
    <div id="cur_5" class="cur">5</div>
```

....НО, есть большое НО...

1. В первом примере взятый [тут](http://webcodius.ru/spravochnik-css/izmenyaem-kursor-myshi-s-pomoshhyu-pravila-css-cursor.html), все работает.
2. Но второй пример не работает, но судя по документации [читать
   тут](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/cursor), должно работать, но увы.
3. третий пример работает, пример спер от сюда [пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/722388/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%8C-%D1%8D%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD-%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0/722415?noredirect=1#comment1089220_722415).
4. Четвертый пример, аналог второго, только отличие в том, что картинка
   скачена на комп, тоже не работает.
5. Ну а пятый пример аналог четвертого, только это для общей
   информации, что путь к картинке не должен содержать пробелы, надо
   путь обернуть в кавычки...

А еще нашел аналогичный вопрос, но там нет моего решения вопроса, там есть ([аналог моего вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/566223/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80-%D0%BC%D1%8B%D1%88%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-drag-and-drop)) ссылка на конвертор, но у меня даже после конвертации картинки не сработало...

Вопрос, что я делаю не так???

Как я понял, формат cur, работает везде,  а вот остальные нет...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Согласно [документации MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_User_Interface/%D0%98%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_URL_%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F_%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0_cursor), изображение, подключаемое в качестве курсора через `url()`, не должно своими размерами превышеть `128x128` пикселей. Изображение, которое вы пытаетесь подключать в примере имеет размер `512x512` пикселей, поэтому оно просто игнорируется браузером.

```css
.cur {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid orange;
  font-size: 20px;
}

#cur_1 {
  cursor: url(http://webcodius.ru/images/cursor.cur), pointer;
}

#cur_2 {
  /* 512x512 */
  cursor: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/d9BcV.png), pointer;
}

#cur_3 {
  /* 128x128 */
  cursor: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/eSWUB.png), pointer;
}

#cur_4 {
  /* без курсора */
  cursor: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="cur_1" class="cur">1</div>
<div id="cur_2" class="cur">2</div> <!-- 512x512 -->
<div id="cur_3" class="cur">3</div> <!-- 128x128 -->
<div id="cur_4" class="cur">4</div> <!-- без курсора -->
```

Все тот же MDN рекомендует не подключать изображения для курсоров больше `32x32` пикселей для большей совсместимости с браузерами.

А на случай, если нужно сделать курсор больше `128x128` пикселей, можно на js написать простенький код, который будет выводить ваше изображение по координатам курсора.

**UPDATE:**
[Список значений](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/c/cursor/#browser-support) `cursor`, которые **не поддерживаются** в некоторых браузерах.

Comment: вот черти, перечитал еше раз , это два ресурса которыми пользуюсь постоянно  https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/cursor  и второй  https://webref.ru/css/cursor , то ли я не внимательно смотрел, то ли нет там ничего о размерах..... а это такой ключевой момент

Comment: @Air по вашей же ссылке в левом меню можно найти и статью, ссылку на которую я в ответе указал - "Using URL values..."

Comment: Cheg, точно, нашел...  еще вопрос...   а  если,  хочу  просто курсор убрать, ему задать прозрачную картинку или есть более изящный спосо?

Comment: @Air cursor:none;

Comment: блииииин, столько лет, ни разу не обратил внимание на none...   благодарю, ты красавчик...))))